# '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' (line 11) and 'str' and can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (line12 )

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

```
x = input("xres\n")
y = input("yres\n")
operation = input("* or /\n")
times = input("amount\n")
int(times)
int(x)
int(y)
increment = 1
while(increment) <= (times) and (operation) == ("*"): #TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
    print((x) * (increment), (y) * (increment)) #TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
    increment = (increment) + (1)
```

I'm pretty sure that (x) and (increment) are integers, why are these errors occurring?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are strings, try `times = int(times)` and so on as `int()` does not convert a value in place but returns an int representation of the value passed as parameter.

Comment: `int(x)` returns a value that is an integer.  It doesn't do an in-place conversion of the variable `x`.

Comment: Correct. In other words, just calling `int(x)` doesn't do anything to `x` in place, you have to reassign it: `x = int(x)`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to put everything in parentheses. This isn't Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

replaced int(x) with x = int(x).
comments helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).